# Character Distributions

Tags: python, string, character

How can I solve this in Python?

Please enter a string of text (the bigger the better): The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.
The distribution of characters in "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain." is:

```
iiiiii
nnnnnn
aaaaa
sss
ttt
ee
hh
ll
pp
yy
m
r
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Hint: Have a look at `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints that exact output:

```
dist={}
ex='The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.'
for ch in ex.lower():
    if ch.isalpha(): dist.setdefault(ch,[]).extend(ch)

out={k:''.join(val) for k,val in dist.iteritems()}.values()
print '\n'.join(sorted(out, key=lambda x: (-len(x),x)))
```

prints:

```
iiiiii
nnnnnn
aaaaa
sss
ttt
ee
hh
ll
pp
yy
m
r
```

Comment: You can use `str.isalpha` instead of `string.letters`.

Comment: @davidroberston i need it printed in the list like a I posted in descending order. is that possible?